# Do I need an antivirus program? Will McAfee work on Ubuntu?

Tags: security, antivirus

I want to know if McAfee anti virus and firewall will work on Ubuntu 12.04.3 and if not what is recommended. I have noticed web pages locking and reporting FBI Virus. If Ubuntu is safe why does my browser lock until I restart my computer?

Comment: No, no Windows anti-virus software will work on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: You do not need an Antivirus for Ubuntu unless you install software from here and there (not from Software Center).

Answer (score 1):

1)  No, the normal, free McAfee won't work on Ubuntu.  (You can buy a subscription, to their linux version - see comment for link)

which is fine because

2) You don't need anti-virus software on Ubuntu

Websites that report you have a virus are lying to you to try and scam you out of money.

Comment: @Tim Wow, I've never seen that before!

Comment: What I was thinking of is the one that comes pre-installed when you re-install windows from the install disc that comes with a Dell.  It's been quite a while since I've used mcafee for anything...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anti-virus on Ubuntu even though there are couple of viruses out there maybe 20 but they won't do any harm to your system, so basically it is no sense to install it but if you really want it so much you can install simple and light and good enough ClamAV run in Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

`sudo apt-get install clamav clamtk`

or using Synaptic Manager or Ubuntu Software Center.